# Second order linear differential equation $t^2\cdot x''- t\cdot x' +4\cdot x= \log(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

I have this problem involving second order linear differential equations. I know how to solve a first order one, but I've been searching for an answer for this one and I don't seem to find any complete solution. 
Here's the equation: $$t^2\cdot x''- t\cdot x' +4\cdot x= \log(t),\;t>0$$
Can someone help, please?

Comment: y=y(t),y=y(x) or y=y(x,t)?

Comment: Sorry, I got it mixed up. I edited it.

Comment: x=x(t) of course

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, I helped with some typesetting, there is a tutorial on mathjax typesetting somewhere on here, or you can click edit on your question to see how it is done. here is tutorial https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved using a substitution by writing $t=e^u$.
$$t=e^u\to\frac{dt}{du}=e^u=t$$
$$\frac{dx}{du}=\frac{dt}{du}\frac{dx}{dt}=t\frac{dx}{dt}$$
Then it can be written that
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
\frac{d^2x}{du^2}=\frac{d}{du}\bigg[\frac{dx}{du}\bigg]&=\frac{d}{dt}\bigg[t\frac{dx}{dt}\bigg]\times\frac{dt}{du} \\
&=\bigg(t\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\frac{dx}{dt}\bigg)\times\frac{dt}{du} \\
&=t^2\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+t\frac{dx}{dt}
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$$
And so the equation can be rewritten to the form 
$$\frac{d^2x}{du^2}-2t\frac{dx}{dt}+4x=\log e^u$$
$$\frac{d^2x}{du^2}-2\frac{dx}{du}+4x=u$$
From this it can be solved as a linear inhomogenous second order differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

$$t^2\cdot x''- t\cdot x' +4\cdot x= \ln(t), t>0$$
Substitute $x=t^m$ to solve the homogeneous equation
$$m^2-2m+4=0 \implies m=1 \pm i\sqrt 3$$
$$ \implies x(t)=C_1t\cos (\sqrt 3 \ln t)+C_2t\sin (\sqrt 3 \ln t)$$

Then use variation of constants for the inhomogeneous equation

$$x=A\ln(t)+B$$